# Vb6 .text property for textbox required

Tags: vb6

I am trying to convert letters to numbers.

I have a sub which ensures only numbers are put into the textbox. 
My questions is will the following code work. I have a textbox(for numbers) and combobbox(for letters)

```
Dim sha As String
Dim stringposition As Long
Dim EngNumber As Long

sha = "abcdefghifjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

stringposition = InStr(1, sha, Mid(1, cmbEngletter.Text, 1))

MsgBox "stringposition"

EngNumber = (txtManuNo.Text * 10) + stringposition
```

My only question above would be will the multiplication work with a .text. I believe it won't because it is a string. Please advise then on how to deal with a situation.

Comment: There are built-in functions for this.  Look into Asc and AscW.  Don't have VB6 so can't be more specific.

Comment: It will work as long as the text in txtManuNo is numeric. VB6 does an implicit conversion for you. I kind a agree with phaedra, and wonder if you are doing a lot more work than needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLng() to convert a string to a Long variable

CLng() will throw an error though if it doesn't like the contents of the string (for example if it contains a non-numeric character), so only use it when you are certain your string will only contain numbers

More forgiving is it to use Val() to convert a string into a numeric variable (a Double by default)

I also suggest you look into the following functions:

- Asc() : returns the ASCII value of a character
- Chr$() : coverts an ASCII value into a character
- Left$() : returns the first characters of a string
- CStr() : convert a number into a string

I think in your code you mean to show the contents of your variable stringposition instead of the word "stringposition", so you should remove the ""

I do wonder though what you are trying to accomplish with your code, but applying the above to your code gives:

```
Dim sha As String
Dim stringposition As Long
Dim EngNumber As Long

sha = "abcdefghifjklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

stringposition = InStr(1, sha, Left$(cmbEngletter.Text, 1))

MsgBox CStr(stringposition)

EngNumber = (Val(txtManuNo.Text) * 10) + stringposition
```

I used Val() because I am not certain your txtManuNo will contain only numbers

To ensure an user can only enter numbers you can use the following code:

```
Private Sub txtManuNo_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  Select Case KeyAscii
    Case vbKeyBack
      'allowe backspace
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9
      'allow numbers
    Case Else
      'refuse any other input
      KeyAscii = 0
  End Select
End Sub
```

An user can still input non-numeric charcters with other methods though, like copy-paste via mouse actions, but it is a quick and easy first filter

Comment: Hi Hrqls I ended up using Val function on the txtManuno. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: What my code does is it has 2 fields(well dozens). As you mentioned above I do also have a sub that ensures only numbers are entered in the text field and combo box to choose the letter. My code takes the value from a manufacture say 208H converts that to value that the client wants and sets that value in few programs and couple of databases.